# How to handle multiple streams from a lobby server to clients

Tags: java, networking, input, stream, connection

So, I'm having an issue with a project of mine. I'm writing a multiplayer lobby system which will enable multiple users to join a lobby, readying themselves by pressing a key. The issue that I'm facing is when two players is readying themselves, the lobby is only printing out a message for the last player who readied themselves. The system is built up in the following way.

Main Server

```
package master;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import main.Lobby;

public class MainServer {

public static final int PORT = 4444;
public static final String HOST = "localhost";
public ArrayList<Lobby> serverList = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    new MainServer().runServer();
}

public void runServer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    // Creating the server

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    System.out.println("Main Server initiated.");

    while (true) {

        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

        try {

            // Establishing the connection to the Lobby server and then adding it to its list
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objectOutputStream.writeObject("Server created successfully.");
            Lobby s = (Lobby) objectInputStream.readObject();
            this.serverList.add(s);
            System.out.println("Server \"" + s.name + "\" added to game list.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The lobby

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import master.MainServer;

/**
 * The Class Server.
 */
public class Lobby implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -21654L;
    public static final int PORT = 4445;
    public static final int MAX_USERS = 5000;
    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    public String name = "Lobby Server";
    public int clientNumber;
    public int playerNumberReady = 0;
    public boolean allPlayersReady = false;
    public boolean OddurIsNice = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Lobby s = new Lobby();
        s.runServer();
    }
    public void runServer() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        registerServer();
        new Thread( () -> {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
                System.out.println("Server waiting for connections...");
                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("User 1 is now connected");
                    clientNumber++;             
 new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeObject("You are connected man");
                        Socket socket2 = serverSocket.accept();
                        System.out.println("User 2 is now connected");
                        clientNumber++;
//                      ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream2 = new ObjectOutputStream(socket2.getOutputStream());
//                      objectOutputStream2.writeObject("You are player number " + clientNumber + ". Waiting for other players to join");
                        new ServerThread(socket, socket2).start();

                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
    }
    private void registerServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // Method for establishing a connection to the MainServer 
        Socket socket = new Socket(MainServer.HOST, MainServer.PORT);

        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);

        System.out.println((String) objectInputStream.readObject());
    }
    public class ServerThread extends Thread {
        public Socket socket = null;
        public Socket socket2 = null;
        ServerThread(Socket socket, Socket socket2) {
            this.socket = socket;
            this.socket2 = socket2;
        }
        public void run() {
            try {       



// This method is for when the client want's to connect to the lobby
                    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    System.out.println("User 1 is now connected");

                    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream2 = new ObjectInputStream(socket2.getInputStream());
                    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream2 = new ObjectOutputStream(socket2.getOutputStream());
                    System.out.println("User 2 is now connected");
                    BoardGameClient joined = (BoardGameClient) objectInputStream.readObject();
                    System.out.println(joined.name + " is now connected.");
                    while(true) {
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject("You joined the server.");
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject("You are player Number " + 1);

                    objectOutputStream.writeObject("Press '1' if you are ready");

                    objectOutputStream2.writeObject("You joined the server.");
                    objectOutputStream2.writeObject("You are player Number " + 2);

                    objectOutputStream2.writeObject("Press '1' if you are ready");

                if(objectInputStream.readObject().equals(1)) {
                    playerNumberReady++;
                }

                if(objectInputStream2.readObject().equals(1)) {
                    playerNumberReady++;
                }

                    if(playerNumberReady != 2) {
                        allPlayersReady = false;
                    } else {
                        allPlayersReady = true;
                    }



                    if (allPlayersReady == false) {
                        objectOutputStream.writeObject("Waiting...");
                        objectOutputStream2.writeObject("Waiting...");
                } 

                    if (allPlayersReady == true) {
                    objectOutputStream.writeObject("Lets GO");
                    objectOutputStream2.writeObject("Lets GO");
                }                           


                    while (true) {
                    System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());
                    }
                    }
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

And the client

```
    package main;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

import master.MainServer;

public class BoardGameClient implements Serializable {

    private int playerName;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6224L;
    public String name = "User";
    private transient Socket socket;
    public transient Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BoardGameClient c = new BoardGameClient();

        if (args.length > 0) {

            c.name = args[0];
        }

        try {

            c.joinServer();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Failed to join server.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void joinServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        socket = new Socket(Lobby.HOST, Lobby.PORT);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        while(true) {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);

        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());
        System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());
        System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());

        int ready = input.nextInt();
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(ready);

        System.out.println(objectInputStream.readObject());



            objectOutputStream.writeObject(name + ": " + inputReader.readLine());
        }
    }
}
```

I sincerely hope, that someone will be able to help me out <3

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's a few things that bug me about this code. Not to sound condescending but you need to avoid rewriting code as much as possible. What happens if you want 3 or more players in the future? Currently you'd have to manually create a whole socket eg socket3, and then rewrite all the code you've already written. This is bad. You've manually spent the time creating 2 sockets and then created 2 streams for both of these sockets etc etc.

This can be automated don't you think?

Secondly, you have a lot of public variables. Unless they are static and final, for the most part you should keep variables as private.

I've tinkered with your lobby class as seen below, which is more scalable. It's not perfect by any means, but I feel illustrates the direction of improvement you should be heading for. Look up SOLID OOP principles, they'll help you guaranteed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * The Class Server.
 */
public class Lobby implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -21654L;
    public static final int PORT = 4445;
    public static final int MAX_USERS = 5000;
    public static final String HOST = "localhost";
    private static final int MIN_USERS = 2;

    private String name = "Lobby Server";
    private int clientNumber;
    private boolean gameRunning = false;

    // set of client connections
    private final Set<ServerThread> clientConnectionThreads = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Lobby s = new Lobby();
        s.createLobby();
    }

    public void createLobby() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // waits for all players to ready up in a different thread
        new Thread(this::waitReady).start();

        registerServer();

        // Listens for clients
        runServer();
    }

    public void runServer() {
        // closes serverSocket automatically in this way
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server waiting for connections...");
            long ids = 0;
            while (!gameRunning) {
                // accepts a new client connection
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                if (clientConnectionThreads.size() >= MAX_USERS) {
                    // tell user server is full and dont add the connection
                } else {
                    // calculates the new id of the incoming player and adds them to the lobby
                    ids++;
                    this.clientConnectionThreads.add(new ServerThread(ids, socket));
                    System.out.println("User " + ids + " is now connected");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * loops until every player is ready and there is enough players and then starts
     * the game.
     */
    public void waitReady() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (areAllReady() && this.clientConnectionThreads.size() >= MIN_USERS) {
                    startGame();
                    return;
                }
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // returns true if all users are ready
    public boolean areAllReady() {
        return clientConnectionThreads.stream().allMatch(ServerThread::isReady);
    }

    public void startGame() {
        System.out.println("Starting game...");
        this.gameRunning = true;
        clientConnectionThreads.forEach(ServerThread::startGame);

        // do game stuff
    }

    // i havent touched this function
    private void registerServer() throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // Method for establishing a connection to the MainServer
        Socket socket = new Socket(MainServer.HOST, MainServer.PORT);

        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);

        System.out.println((String) objectInputStream.readObject());
    }

    public class ServerThread extends Thread {
        private final Socket socket;
        private final ObjectInputStream in;
        private final ObjectOutputStream out;
        private final long id;
        boolean ready = false;

        private ServerThread(long id, Socket socket) throws IOException {
            // does some basic initialization
            this.socket = socket;
            this.id = id;
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            // starts this connection thread
            this.start();
        }

        public boolean isReady() {
            return ready;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                // sets up the client and waits for their input
                BoardGameClient joined = (BoardGameClient) in.readObject();
                System.out.println(joined.name + " is now connected.");
                out.writeObject("You joined the server.");
                out.writeObject("You are player Number " + id);
                out.writeObject("Press '1' if you are ready");
                out.flush();

                // waits for user to return ready
                while (!ready) {
                    try {
                        int input = in.readInt();
                        System.out.println("input: " + input);
                        ready = input == 1;
                    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                out.writeObject("Waiting for players...");

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void startGame() {
            // send client message etc etc
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I basically didn't change any of the other classes, except a few lines within the client class to make this work. (I've changed the ready input type from writeObject() to writeInt())
I haven't tested this for problems, but I know it works at least on a basic level.

I also suggest using writeUTS()/readUTS() instead of writeObject()/readObject() for sending and receiving Strings across streams as this will add extra complexity to the code.